# doctrine sum of values depending on account source

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I'm currently standing in front of an issue that I don't really know how to solve in doctrine.

This is my current Query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) FROM AccountingBundle:Entity:Transaction t WHERE t.SourceAccount = ?1 or t.TargetAccount = ?1
```

While `TargetAccount` should be positive accounted and `SourceAccount` should be negative accounted.
I don't really want to do 2 Queries as with this doctrine and PostgreSQL are faster.

I found an possible solution use

```
CASE WHEN t.SourceAccount = ?1 THEN ... ELSE ...
```

But I didn't yet find a way to tell doctrine the value is negative.
Can any one tell me how to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't doing:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.SourceAccount = ?1 THEN t.ammount * -1 ELSE t.ammount)
FROM
  AccountingBundle:Entity:Transaction t
WHERE
  t.SourceAccount = ?1 or t.TargetAccount = ?1
```

solve your problem?

**EDIT:** the trick here is to multiply the amount by -1 making it a negative number

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible.

Comment: never heard of the * -1 so far. Thanks for the tip